# putting json array into d3 .range

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

I am trying to populate a d3 scale with a json array. When I do it like this it works:

```
    var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(6))
        .range(["#602320","#D40000","#EA627A","#FF0000","#FFB600"]);
```

I need to dynamically populate the range with some different colors. I am creating a json array like so:

```
            var chordcolorsetsplit = chordcolorvalues.split(",");
            var chordcolorset = JSON.stringify(chordcolorsetsplit);

            alert(chordcolorset);
```

The alert returns a string that looks like this:

[image: output of chordcolorset var]

however when I try and use this in the .range it does not work correctly. Any ideas on the correct syntax?

```
    var fill = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(d3.range(6))
        .range(chordcolorset);
```

For reference, the chordcolorvalues array looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What does `chordcolorvalues` look like?

Comment: By the looks of it `range` accepts a standard array rather than a JSON.  Have you tried passing it `chordcolorvalues`?

Comment: chordcholorvalues doesnt work, i have updated the question with what that array looks like.! Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry try using `chordcolorsetsplit` as the `range` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to simply pass a split variable. In my example above this means using chordcolorsetsplit inside the range.